# How to check if cron job works?

Tags: macos, cron

I use `crontab -e` without `sudo` to edit cron jobs and add the following line there -

```
20 22 23 10 * date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" >> ~/Documents/log.txt
```

then I check the log file and it doesn't contain the date and time.

I tried to edit `crontab` as root, but it also doesn't update the file. What could be wrong here? Is there any way to see the log of cron jobs execution?

P.S. Update crontab created under root:

```
0/5 * * * * /bin/date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" >> /tmp/log.txt
0/5 * * * * echo >> /tmp/log2.txt
```

`log2.txt` is created now.

Comment: crontab does not understand ~ you need to give the full path

Comment: @Mark, I used full path (instead of ~) with root crontab - the result is the same, no record in the file.

Comment: Also path might not be set use the full path to date - also note for OSX launchd is preferred to cron

Comment: @Mark, I am trying to use `/bin/date` and `echo` now (see updated question).

Answer (score 7):

Your `cron` error message are sent to the `mail` account of the user that is running the `cron` job.

Type `mail` at the command line to see the messages. For a list of `mail` commands, see [man mail](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/mail.1).

You should be getting mail with an error message something to the effect of:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

As for you command and why it's not working, it's because the "%" sign is a "newline" character, meaning that it tells the shell to "go to the next line."  So, after it encounters the first "%" it goes to the next line and it never sees the rest of the command.  This is confirmed by the "unexpected EOF while looking for the matching ' "  '(double quote).

The local man page for crontab (`man crontab`)is quite sparce with details and I am speculating it's because `cron` has been deprecated for [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)<sup>1</sup>.  However, the crontab manpage from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/crontab) explains it

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>   run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.  The command can optionally be prefixed by "`@AppleNotOnBattery`" to tell cron not to run the command when functioning on battery power.  For example, the "sixth" field when using this option would appear something like `"@AppleNotOnBattery /usr/bin/touch /tmp/foo"`

**Your fix:**

So, what you need to do, is "escape" the "%" character with a backslash (\) so that it tells it to interpret it literally.

Your command should be:

```
0/5 * * * * /bin/date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S" >> /tmp/log.txt
```

---

<sup>1</sup> From `man crontab`:  *(Darwin note: Although cron(8) and crontab(5) are officially supported under Darwin, their functionality has been absorbed into launchd(8), which provides a more flexible way of automatically executing commands.  See launchctl(1) for more information.)*