# command silently failing when running from the root's crontab

Tags: terminal, diskutil, cron

I have a script that runs diskutil and since diskutil needs permissions to run I'm running the script from the root's crontab.

Steps:

1. sudo su root
2. crontab -e
3. - - - - - sh /test.sh
4. Nothing ever happens

After typing sudo su root, typing sh /test.sh successfully runs the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly is `test.sh` stored?

Comment: to be safe both in: /test.sh and /Users/me/test.sh - after typing sudo su root and then pwd the path is /Users/me/

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258429/119271) regarding diagnosing `cron` (you should be using `launchd`, BTW).  Also, you should be using the full path to `test.sh` because root doesn’t inherit your path.

Comment: I can't use mail in root made, and no luck with using the full path to the test.sh file - I have just tried to run test.sh using a launchd .plist file, but no luck - is it possible to run my .sh using launchd?

Comment: Not the Mail app (GUI), but `mail` from the command line - very different.  Also, how are you even putting files in the root folder?  By default, macOS doesn’t let you write there, much less execute from there.   I think there’s a lot missing from the Q.

Comment: I know the mail you speak of as I was using it to debug crontab when not in root mode. I switched to running crontab in root since diskutil wouldn't run when not...and now I can't see mail since mail isn't available in root. I'm basically trying to run a script that checks if a hard drive is connected and if so open an app - that's it.

Comment: In your script, do you specify the binary with its full path?